# invalid color value: red strike error message [Git + intelliJ]

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, git-config

I was following the *More color attributes* section graphics on the [Git 2.10](https://github.com/blog/2242-git-2-10-has-been-released) release note. Going through which upgraded the git to 2.10.0 and made changes to global `.gitconfig` resulting as follows -

```
[color "diff"]
    old = red strike
    new = green italic
```

But now that I load a git project on intelliJ [15.0.3 in case] and after few changes try accessing the ***`Version Control`*** window, I get to see the following error -

> error: invalid color value: red strike fatal: bad config variable
>   'color.diff.old' in file '/Users/xyz/.gitconfig' at line 21

This keeps me away from looking at the diffs using the intelliJ-UI. Though I can still access the same using the terminal `git diff`.

**Is there a way to overcome the same? Or some change in intelliJ as well along with the upgradation of git?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the same problem occurred due to ***IntelliJ using an old version of git***.

- In the IntelliJ preferences go to *Version Control* > *Git*.
- Find the *Path to Git executable*.
- Clicking the **Test** button next to it should show you the version of the binary used by IntelliJ.

If it is below 2.10 you might want to change the path to the one used from the command line.

You can find the correct path by calling `which git` on the command line.

Comment: thanks, almost forgot sometime back intelliJ was smart enough to auto detect the path of git and that needed an update post some mash up :)